# Google Cloud SQL connection to flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform

I'm on the internet for 3 days trying to find something which would help me to set up PostreSQL server on Google Cloud and my flutter app. There is absolutely nothing neither in documentation or anywhere on the internet for flutter app how to connect it, set it up, or even do authentication without firebase. I tried to get help in console support page and it directed me here which I understand is not the best question for SO but I got no other option.. So can anyone help me with it or is flutter only design to work with firebase or is google cloud not ready for flutter yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since SQL Databases should never be accessed over the internet directly, it would be a good idea to have a web endpoint which exposes a limited API, sending http requests for the operations wanted. One way to approach this would be to have your Flutter app trigger [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions), which would then connect to [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres) (the managed PostgreSQL service on GCP).

[Here is documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions) on how to connect Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL. Finally, [here is an external blog post](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-flutter-app-powered-by-google-cloud-functions-3eab0df5f957) on how to use Flutter with Cloud Functions. Please note that we cannot guarantee the accuracy of external information, and it should serve as a reference to get you started.