# Trying to get data from Google Cloud SQL in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-sql

I'm making a Flutter app with a login page, and I've been trying to query data from a Google Cloud MySQL server and serve it to my app. I was able to replicate the result I want in python using bigquery but I need something like that but in a dart/flutter version(any other ways work too as long as the result is the same)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: have you considered using a cloud function to proxy the service ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud SQL connection to flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406293/google-cloud-sql-connection-to-flutter)

Comment: @Prabir I found this one but I've had a hard time following the instructions, will keep trying to see if I can get it

Comment: @g2server I've tried but i don't know how I would call the cloud function in flutter

Comment: @PaulAfriyie Can you explain what is the difficulty you are facing while understanding the  answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406293/google-cloud-sql-connection-to-flutter), specifically which step you are not able to understand?

Comment: @Prabir I don't know how to activate cloud functions through flutter, and after that all tutorials iv found only tell me how to connect to cloud SQL not how to then control it afterwards with the cloud functions. Iv heard a lot of talk about firebase and flutter so maybe that instead?

Comment: @PaulAfriyie, I have posted an answer, which, I hope, will make you understand the things better.

Comment: @Prabir thank you! As my free trial with google cloud has ended ill have to wait a few weeks before I can put it into action but I think I have an understanding of where to go using your answer, I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to connect to the Cloud SQL databases directly over the internet from the client application. So one should avoid connecting to the Cloud SQL database directly from the Flutter Application. In this case, it would be a good idea to create an API endpoint to do the operations in Cloud SQL and hit that endpoint from the Flutter Application.

To achieve the above, we can follow these steps:

1. Deploy a Http Cloud Functions which connects to the Cloud SQL
   database

   In this step we have to deploy a [Http Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http) and from the Cloud Functions we can connect to the Cloud SQL database. Inside the Cloud Functions we can do the operations on the Cloud SQL database. [This document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions) explains how to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Functions.
2. Call the Http Cloud Functions URL from the Flutter Application

   After deploying the Cloud Functions, we will get a unique URL for it, which looks like this `https://GCP_REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME`. We have to call this URL from the Flutter Application. [This blog](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-flutter-app-powered-by-google-cloud-functions-3eab0df5f957) explains how to call the Cloud Functions URL from the Flutter Application.